Can we have a badge for popular person?
If there is not already...Could we have a series of badges for popular person? Like having questions or answers with an total large amount of pageviews. I know there is a popular question/answer badge. Instead of 1 question with 10,000 views...100 questions which collectively total 10,000 views. 

For these types of network wide suggestions the best place to post is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

So what would be the difference with the popular question/answer badge?

@JeromyAnglim i'm not allowed to post on meta.stackoverflow hahhaa if you want to migrate that would be kool :)

@StevenJeuris it would highlight individuals who had a history of generating popular and famous questions or those who did not generate popular or famous questions but still were popular or famous because of total volume of work.

That's what you want out of it, but how would it work? It's description is still ambiguous.

@StevenJeuris did the edit i make clear up the ambiguity?

The SE system is already broken by letting users exploit a large quantity of low quality answers to gain reputation ( upvote is +10, while downvote is only -2 with -1 penalty to voter). Making such a badge for questions would just result in more users spamming poor questions. If you want to know who invests time to drive traffic to the site then just look at the list of announcer, booster, and publicist badge holders.
